# compile code in VB are the same as C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Let's say that I have an entire project build in C# and other project build VB and I made a reference to this VB project Because this two projects need to interact between each other. Is this possible? the compiled code of this two project could live together??. Also if i made the same project VB and C# the compiled version are the same??

Comment: Yes, all .NET languages can reference other .NET assemblies. Have you tried it? What actual problem are you having?

Comment: Yes, as long as you are talking about **VB.NET**.

Comment: Same project in VB and C# would compile slightly differently.  You shouldn't notice the difference however running the applications, given all other factors are equal.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language

Comment: @ildjarn at the day I don't have troubles I just want to validate here,before actually refer between projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both compile into intermediate language (IL), and you can use a VB.NET library with C# and vice versa.

If you want to examine the compiled versions of both languages I recommend you download [ILSpy](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx&q=ilspy&ei=qWRiT7nwFoiP8gOMp43sBw&usg=AFQjCNHrBCPiPBLs5qWwAnf2ZygTWwrjXA) - you can open up any .NET assembly with it. There are a tiny few things that are possible in the one but not in the other, and IL has features not implemented in either :)

Comment: +1. Also make sure your assemblies are marked CLS compliant and the compilers will ensure you don't have any problems. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx

Answer (score 1):

.net / clr uses an intermediate language.
also referred as [IL](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).

it is similiar to Java's ByteCode

code program written in c# and vb may differ in a the resulting IL-Code but,
the executional result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can mix projects written in different languages.

There are some subtle differences in how the C# and VB compiler produce code from the source code, but most code will be identical once it's compiled.

One of those subtle differences for example is that local variables in VB are initialised to zero, while local variables in C# are not initialised.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create empty solution
2. Right click solution name in solution explorer, add existing project, add VB project
3. Right click solution name in solution explorer, add existing project, add C# project
4. Solution Explorer>VB project>"My Project">References>Add... button>Projects>Select the C# project>OK

Now you can access public methods in the other project.